# python variable reset inside loop

Tags: python

```
x=0
while x <= 5:
    i = 0
    while i <= 5:
        print("J", end=" ")
        i+=1
    x+=1
    print()
```

Can anyone explain me why the var `i` get reset after while loop.  Isn't supposed to be remained like the var `x` ?

Comment: It is because you set `i=0` inside of your outermost loop. If you don't want to reset it, assign it outside of the loop like you do with `x`

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "reset", and it's unclear which while loop you're talking about.  More detail needed.

Comment: What does this have to do with `bash`?

Comment: `x=0` executes once while `i = 0` executes 6 times

Comment: So does it mean that any variable that I put inside a loop will get reset.  Now it kinda make sense now..  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
x=0
while x <= 5:
    i = 0
    while i <= 5:
        print("J", end=" ")
        i+=1
    x+=1
    print(i)
```

Yes, variable i will be equal to zero because at the start of your outer `while` loop, you have `i = 0`. So that is why.